# Automate change background to white on all images?

Tags: background

I am working with model images that our standard images have to be the item with white background. Ive had vendors sending me images with their item only with off white background and I have to do 600 images a day and it gets annoying. Is there a way to automate a white background without taking out the main image and do it all at once to save me time?

Comment: If they're vendors...then you're paying them...why not simply stipulate that they must shoot their images with blown out backgrounds?

Comment: They do give us a white background but its like "off white" just want to make it clean and bright and make the item stand out.

Comment: Can you upload an example image you would normally manually clean up, so we can get a better idea of how much contrast there is in the images?

Comment: An example or two is really needed then. "off white" is a very large range...

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the consistency of the photos and maybe more importantly, the colour of the subject. PS has the ability to do selections on colour range, so you record your actions on processing a single image to create a PS Action that you can then apply to other images.

If this works, then you can apply the action in a batch process against all your images and let it run.

If your images don't allow for the easy color range selection though, you won't be able to automate it like this. Manually doing the selection will be very time consuming.